# Realtime database - orderByChild() works with once(), doesn't work with get()

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a database with following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
      ".indexOn": ["time", "timestamp"],
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and data with format

```
users
  |_ uid
      |_ time
      |_ timestamp
```

When I perform a query (with Cloud Functions) using `once()` it works perfectly fine

```js
await admin.database().ref("users").orderByChild("timestamp")
  .once("value", (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      functions.logger.log(childSnapshot.key);
    });
  });
```

but when I perform query with `get()`

```js
await admin.database().ref("users").orderByChild("timestamp")
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      functions.logger.log(childSnapshot.key);
    });
  });
```

I get following error:

> Error: No index defined for timestamp at IndexMap.get

Note that it's not the same error when index is not defined at all - in such situation error looks like this:

> Error: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "timestamp", for path "/users"

I was adding new entries after defining index, so all the data should be indexed (in theory). Of course I could just use `once()` but now I don't know whether my data is being actually indexed or not. Could anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

This is a known issue in the JavaScript SDK, that seems to also surface in the Admin SDK for Node.js. As far as I know there is no fix yet, but the workaround with `once()` is indeed valid. If I know more about a fix for the issue, I'll post it here.

Comment: Ah, I see - good to know that it's not an issue with indexing. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: I didn't realize .get() was a valid method for node admin sdk, I can't find any documentation for it. Could you share a resource? Otherwise as far as I know it has always been `once` and `on`

Comment: In JavaScript `get()` is pretty much meant to be a 1:1 alias for `once()`. But clearly something went wrong there. :-/    This should normally be documented in https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Database-1, but something seems missing there too. I'm checking on that too, and will file bugs as needed.   Sorry about the messy releases, and thanks for catching them!