# Error: No index defined for id when using forEach

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to get a list of my data in order using Firebase.
When using the `orderByChild` function along with `forEach` I received this error:

```
Error: No index defined for id
```

Here is the data:

```
<UID1>
-----some data...
<UID2>
-----some data...
dinos
---bronto
   |--- id: 100
---stega
   |--- id: 200
---tyrano
   |--- id: 110
```

Here is my ruleset:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "dinos": {
      ".indexOn": "id"
    },
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

And here is the code to get the data:

```
    async function orderDinos(){
        let orderedDinos = await db.ref('dinos').orderByChild('id')

        let get = await orderedDinos.get()
        // console.log(get.val())
        get.forEach((myDino) => {
            console.log(myDino.val())
        })
    }
```

What am I doing wrongly? Why isn't my code working?

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

There is an issue with `get()` and indexes in some cases. We're working on a fix, but in the meantime you can work around the problem by calling `once()` instead of `get()`.

Also see: [Realtime database - orderByChild() works with once(), doesn't work with get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448142/realtime-database-orderbychild-works-with-once-doesnt-work-with-get)